# product of a vector times an asymmetric matrix vs a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, vector-analysis

As a school assignment, im currently finding the gradient for different functions, however of the functions are the same (where x is a vector, A is a matrix, b a vector, c a scalar):
$$f(x)=x^{T}Ax+b^{T}x+c$$
Except that A is not symmetric in one function, and symmetric in the other, however this shouldn't make a difference since $A \cdot x$ simply provides a new vector, or am i completely wrong here?

Comment: The gradient of $f(X)=x^{T}Ax+x^{T}b+c$ at point $X_0$ is indeed a vector which is $(A+A^T)X_0+b$

Answer (score 0):

Do out the algebra. In one case, there'll be a simplification that arises from $a_{jk} = a_{kj}$; in the other, that simplification won't be there. For instance, I might give you a function of a matrix $A$: 
$$
h(A) = {A + A^t}
$$
and another function
$$
g(A) = 2A
$$
These two are the same if $A$ is symmetric, but different if not. In much the same way, the formula you derive will be "more simplifiable" if $A$ is symmetric than if it isn't. Imagine, for instance, that there's a term like $a_{jk} - a_{kj}$ -- for symmetric matrices, that disappears.